# Unable to start receiver: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException with android JellyBean

Tags: android, json, multithreading, httprequest, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I'm trying to develop a widget that updates itself every minute by a json resource, my problem is that when i try to launch it on jellybean it crashes, while with gingerbread works.

I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11347754/how-to-avoid-networkonmainthread-exception-without-using-asynctask) that i must move all internet connection to the main thread, right?
At the moment i've a class called HttpRequest:

```
public class HttpRequest {    
    private String url;

    public HttpRequest(String url)
    {       
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String GetContent() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException
    {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

        String html = "";
        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            str.append(line);
        }
        in.close();
        html = str.toString();
        return html;
    }
}
```

Every minute is called updateAppWidget() that is a method of WidgetProvider class.
Inside updateAppWidget() there is:

```
HttpRequest r = new HttpRequest("http://www.hwlogos.com/test.json");
remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.ip, r.GetContent());
```

Can you tell me how solve it steep by steep? 
thanks

Comment: No, you need to move OFF the main thread.

Comment: I've written about this exception and why it is thrown in Android 3.0 and above. Check out this [**post**](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html) for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As proposed, *AsyncTask* is the way to go. Change your code like this:

```
private class HttpRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, String> {

    private Context context;

    protected String doInBackground(Context... contextParam) {
        context = contextParam[0];
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.hwlogos.com/test.json");
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

        String html = "";
        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            str.append(line);
        }
        in.close();
        html = str.toString();
        return html;
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(String html) {
         AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
         RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
         remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.ip, html);
         appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(new ComponentName(context, WidgetProvider .class), remoteViews);
     }
}
```

Note the code in *onPostExecute* that does the extra work required to update an app widget.

Then start the asynchronous task like this:

```
 new HttpRequestTask().execute(context);
```

Comment: The easiest solution is to make *HttpRequestTask* class an inner class of the *WidgetProvider* class. Another solution is to add *remoteView* as an instance variable of *HttpRequestTask* and set it via a *setRemoteView* method before you call *execute*.

Comment: I tried in this way: http://pastebin.com/e2wDyBPW and Log.i("ERROR", "RECEIVED ID: " + remoteViews.toString()); every time is called prints a different id...

I tried to give the remoteViews object through the constructor of Downloader class and there is the same problem.

Comment: You are creating a new *remoteViews* instance every time you call *Downloader*. Is this really what you want? Shouldn't you create the *remoteViews* instance once and call the *Downlader* many times?

Comment: No, should be 1 remoteView for each widget...
What is wrong whit this code? I get the id when i need it...

Comment: I've changed my code and added the required code to update the app widget from the async task.

Comment: thanks, it works!

p.s.
AppWidgetManager.getWidget(context); should be getIstance

Comment: now there is another problem...
when i add 2 or more widget, when onPostExecute( is called, all widget are updated with the same html!

Comment: You better start a new question for this problem. There you can post the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to move your network connections *off of* the main thread and onto a background thread. Later versions of Android will crash the app if you use the network on the main thread.

The most straightforward solution will be to use an `AsyncTask`, which will do some work on a separate thread (doing your network fetches) and then enable you to do subsequent work on the main thread when it's done.

There's an example in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example), and many others can be found on SO or Google.

Answer (score 0):

Call your function from bellow code [ from thread ]

Step 1 :

Instead of this two lines

```
HttpRequest r = new HttpRequest("http://www.hwlogos.com/test.json");
remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.ip, r.GetContent());
```

Call bellow Lines of code,

```
    Thread thread = new Thread()
    {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          try {

            // CALL YOUR FUNCTION FROM HERE
            HttpRequest r = new HttpRequest("http://www.hwlogos.com/test.json");            
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.ip, r.GetContent());

          } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
    };

thread.start();
```

Step 2:

if above function do not work for you then

use this Reference [Link](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-http-access-with-httpurlconnection-to-download-image-example/).

i hope this will work for you. Thanks.

Comment: Declare this "RemoteView remoteViews" object as global in your class.

Comment: i think you create "RemoteView remoteViews = new " inside some function.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/BBK1Zq2N i'm getting this

DEBUG: Id is: android.widget.RemoteViews@410917a8
DEBUG: The real id is: android.widget.RemoteViews@40dd7470